# Invalid CORS with Microsoft Edge and EventSource

Tags: cors, microsoft-edge, eventsource

I just set up a fresh new project and I want to use EventSource. I would like it to be compatible with the main browsers, including Edge. EventSource being not supported by Edge, I had to install a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource).

My client is a vue cli application running at the address http://localhost:8080/. I added the following code in the main.js file:

```
// Client - main.js

import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'

//Not sure if this one is necessary, so far I got the same result with and without it.
require('../node_modules/eventsource/lib/eventsource.js');

//polyfill for Edge
require('../node_modules/eventsource/lib/eventsource-polyfill.js'); 


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

var source = new EventSource(
  'http://localhost:3000/',
  {withCredentials: true}
);

source.onmessage = function(e) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.warn("My message: " + jsonData.msg);
};
```

Then, the following code is running on my Node.js server at http://localhost:3000/:

```
//Server

var express     = require("express"),
    app         = express(),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
      "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    });

    setInterval(function(){

      const date = new Date();
      const data = date.getTime()

      console.log('writing ' + data);
      res.write('data: ' + JSON.stringify({ msg : data }) + '\n\n');
    }, 1000);
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening at Port " + port);
});
```

I've already added some CORS headers, or EventSource wouldn't work on chrome.
The code above works great on Chrome, Firefox and Opera (I receive a message every second). But Edge gives me the following error:

```
SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:8080' did not find 'http://localhost:8080' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

I don't get why it doesn't work. Could there be a problem with the polyfill? Have I not imported it correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use **[event-source-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-source-polyfill)** instead. Please include polyfill's eventsource to your page like below code (remove previous eventsource and eventsource-polyfill js files ):

```html
require('../node_modules/event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js')
```

It works both in IE 11 and Edge on my side.

Comment: `event-source-polyfill` seems to work with `{withCredentials}` whereas `eventsource` did not. My SSE ny works with CORS. Thanks!